# QGIS / QField Sync Warning "Non ASCII character detected"

Tags: qgis, qfieldsync

I wanted to sync a project with the cloud but received this warning:

> Non ASCII character detected in the layer filename. Working with file
> paths that are not in ASCII might cause problems. It is highly
> recommended to rename them to ASCII encoded paths.

It still works out, but I don't want to cause problems. I don't have an idea what to do to solve this and I need an explanation what exactly the problem is (I don't understand the warning properly) and how I can fix it.

Could the letter "ü" cause this problem?

Comment: I believe that you are right. QField probably prefers  "ASCII printable characters (character code 32-127)" https://www.ascii-code.com/. Characters in the extented set 128-255, like the u-umlaut, can make troubles.

Comment: Yes, the letter "ü" was the problem